# SceneKit - Fix screen frame to camera edges

Tags: xcode, 3d, scenekit, perspectivecamera, 3dcamera

I'm working on a app that renders a 3D scene that simulates a real space into an iPhone making its screen become a hollow box, as seen in the sketch below:

(note the camera position order down below)

[image: Sketch of proposal]

The problem is on how to calculate the camera parameters to make the box look real fixed to the screen edges.

Is this feasible through SceneKit?

Comment: VERY WELL ASKED QUESTION!!!!!!!!!!! and a good question, too!!!

Comment: I managed to solve it. The whole thing is a math problem, not a programming one! I'll post an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @RamonBalthazar were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

In this configuration the camera's `zNear` plane corresponds to the screen of the iPhone. From that you can can derive a `z` position from the camera's field of view and the screen's width (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257664/relation-between-horizontal-vertical-and-diagonal-field-of-view)).

Comment: LEGENDARY status for succinctness in answers maintained!